# The resource is not on the build path of a java project?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a Maven project on my Eclipse. When I perform call hierarchy I get the message:

> The resource is not on the build path of a java project.

What needs to be configured for this?

Comment: What are you doing call hierarchy on?

Comment: Is the class that contains the method in the build path of the Maven java project?

Answer (score 13):

I followed the following steps it worked:

1. Properties->project facets->check java->ok
2. convert to maven project.

Comment: I had to do something similar to the above.
1. Right-click on the maven project
2. Click on Properties > Project Facets
3. Click on "convert to faceted form"
4. Ensure that Java was checked in the "Project Facet" column and then click Apply

Comment: I do not have "Project Facets" available as an option.

Comment: My Hero!  Damn lack of source has been killing me on this project and I didnt have time to fix it, your answer fixed it thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're expecting a call hierarchy in your own code, ensure that all sources are located in the src/main/java directory.

Have you installed the Eclipse m2e plugin? Does your Eclipse recognize the project as a Maven project? (right click > maven > convert to maven project)

Comment: and the project builds ?

Comment: well, this should be the 1st thing to solve. You should open a new question for it. Does it build using maven only (using `mvn clean install` command ?)

Answer (score 1):

I have this quite often. Seems bug in Eclipse. Quit/restart Eclipse seems the easiest to get things working again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on a Maven project, every resource must be included in a pom.xml file. If not, the external file must be included as a jar file.
Also, if you are not able to open the call hierarchy, the project which is being referred must be open in your Eclipse workspace.