# Eclipse > Remote System Plugins > Error : the resource is not on the build path of a script project

Tags: eclipse, system

I use Eclipse and the plugins Remote System to edit file in ssh in other server.

Sometimes when i work on a file i have the error :  The resource is not on the build path of a script project . And This error appears ten times when a popup. it's very nasty !

I try this : [I am getting resource not on the buildpath of the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170666/i-am-getting-resource-not-on-the-buildpath-of-the-project) but it's not a projet but a remote system, i don't have the same windows.

Thanks

Djoo

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem with project cloned from mercurial
this helped: 
1 - right click on project folder
2 - find "configure" from popup menu
3 - I added php support as it is a php project, that had no builders

hope helps you too