# Issues with Eclipse setup on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, buildpath

I am facing setup issues in my eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu 12.04 on Virtual box.

Firstly i was facing issue same as:
[Eclipse Open declaration in Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207074/eclipse-open-declaration-in-java-project)
I tried everything mentioned here, but nothing seems to be working for me...

Then I explored some more, and get another error message similar to:
[I am getting resource not on the buildpath of the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170666/i-am-getting-resource-not-on-the-buildpath-of-the-project)
As per its 1st answer, 2nd point go to "Java Build Path", I tried going there, but i cannot find any "Java Build Path" section in my project property.

When I click on Project properties, it shows only options given in the following screenshot:

[image]

I know this is some easy setup issue, but i am unable to handle it.

Comment: Sounds like your project may not be a Java project - you should have Java Build Path, Java Code Style, Java Compiler, Java Editor, ... in the project properties if it is a Java project.

Comment: It is a java project only. Infact it is building fine from following command in terminal:
mvn clean install -DskipTests

Comment: Do you have the `JDT` installed in your `Eclipse` distribution? Sounds like you are using a naked install.

Comment: @user3368154 Being able to run `maven` does not indicate that the project is an `Eclipse` project, did you try to create a new Java Project from scratch?

Comment: @Andreas I tried installing jdt as per this https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Installing+the+Java+Development+Tools
But i cannot find Eclipse JDT in Programming language tab

Comment: @andreas, new project is giving all options like "java build path" etc... But still i dont know why it is not showing up in current project. I know people who are working on this project and for them it is working fine

Comment: Did you use the "Existing Maven Projects" import when setting up the project?

Comment: Thanks a tonn Andreas... Earlier when I was trying to import it as "Existing Maven Projects" it was giving some error... So i switched back to "import as normal java project".
But on your question I again tried import as "Existing Maven Projects" and everything seams to be wroking now... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The answer is a write-up of the discussion in the comments:*

If you are on `Ubuntu 12.04` and install `Eclipse` you could end up with a bare-bones install without the Java Development Tools (`JDT`).

After installing the package manually via `Help` -> `Install New Software` and then searching for `Programming Languages / Eclipse Java Development Tools` Java development should work.

For `maven` projects you should use the import `Existing Maven Projects` instead of importing it as a java project.