# maven project in eclipse: different maven version issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import

I have java project which builds fine via:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

In my previous eclipse version (with m2e installed), when I used to import it as "mvn project", it used to work fine.

But because of some problems i re-installed my OS.

Now when I try to import it as "mvn project", it gives me following error: [Issues with Eclipse setup on Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886557/issues-with-eclipse-setup-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Then I tried some more and built project as:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests eclipse:eclipse
```

And tried importing it as mvn project. Now it imports fine, but I have some issues:

1. The import still have some problem. Earlier it is showing all
   modules as different projects. But I wanted to import it as one
   project (earlier it used to get import as 1 project, which helps in
   navigation and putting breakpoints)
2. Reason of this behavior?: Is this because of different version of two maven (command line and eclipse). If yes, how can i handle that. I anyway don't need to built project from eclipse.

Comment: Why are you using an old Eclipse version. Why not Eclipse Luna? Apart from that if you using import as Maven project you shouldn't use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` anymore. What do you mean by `But I wnated to import as one project`?

Comment: I did not say old eclipse version. I have eclipse Luna only. And maven version 3.0.4. 

Import gave me 12 individual projects and one project which lists all 12 under it. The umbrella project has 12 modules defined in it which translated to 12 eclipse project. Umbrella project still has this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886557/issues-with-eclipse-setup-on-ubuntu-12-04. And other projects are independent projects, not as one

Comment: Are you searching for Working set ?